# Minimum system requirements for Monero?

Tags: full-node, system-requirements

What are the minimum system requirements to run a full Monero node?

Specifically:

- How much RAM do I need?
- How much disk space is required?
- Is a SSD needed to sync in a reasonable period of time?
- Is it possible to run a Monero node on Raspberry Pi or similar device?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Since Monero moved to LMDB in January, RAM requirements are now quite low. It is possible to run a full node with 1GB of RAM
2. The amount of hard drive space needed will vary by OS. I have not yet seen a blockchain over 20GB. The blockchain continues to grow, but pruning options (such as provided by Aeon a Monero fork) will likely become available eventually
3. A SSD is not required but will significantly decrease sync time. Depending on your setup sync time for the entire blockchain can vary between 10 minutes (on powerful systems) to several days. The current master in GitHub has LMDB improvements over the tagged release.
4. Yes, multiple users have been running Monero on Raspberry Pi for over a year at this point: https://forum.getmonero.org/20/general-discussion/267/a-step-by-step-guide-to-running-a-full-node-on-raspberry-pi-2